# MSBuild cannot find a reference - ReactJs.NET

Tags: msbuild, reactjs.net

After upgrading Newtonsoft.Json to version 9.0.0 and ReactJS.Net packages to 2.5.0, the TransformBabel.proj stopped working:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="TransformBabel">
      <!-- ReactJS.NET - Transpile JavaScript via Babel -->
      <UsingTask AssemblyFile="$(OutputPath)\React.MSBuild.dll" TaskName="TransformBabel" />
      <Target Name="TransformBabel">
          <TransformBabel SourceDir="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" />
      </Target>
  </Project>
```

Returning the following:

```
TransformBabel.proj(6, 3): error MSB4018: The "TransformBabel" task failed unexpectedly.
[Exec] TransformBabel.proj(6, 3): error MSB4018: React.TinyIoC.TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type: React.IReactSiteConfiguration ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'React.ReactSiteConfiguration' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

It seems that it cannot load the Newtonsoft 6.0.0.0 version. The web.config has an assembly redirection:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

But I am not sure that, as it is starting a new msbuild process, if it is being ignored. I would like to hint msbuild the location of the assembly, but no success until now.

Comment: Does Newtonsoft.Json.dll exist on `$(OutputPath)`?

Comment: @KMoraz yes, but not the 6.0.0.0 version.

Comment: So that's explains the error. Consume React.MSBuild.dll from its origin instead of the project output path. See [usage](https://github.com/babel/babel.github.io/blob/845d86b6c08dbc066859ad9611b554f606801d41/_includes/tools/msbuild/usage.md)

Comment: @KMoraz by origin you mean the nuget packages folder?

Comment: Yes, or any other location it exist other than the output path.

Comment: @KMoraz there is no Newtonsoft there too :/

Comment: And does it fails on the same error? if so try adding v6.0.0.0 manually

Comment: Actually,it throws another error (failed to find React.Core), as React.MSBuild depends on React.Core, which dependes on various assemblies, including Newtonsoft.Json. Is there any way I could make msbuild redirect to Newtonsoft.Json 9? Otherwise, I would have to copy the whole dependency tree.

Comment: I've tried latest build using `Install-Package React.MSBuild`. It works without as expected. I think in your case your project holds another reference to Newtonsoft.Json, so try set it with Specific Version=true and Copy Local=false

Comment: @KMoraz Yes, another assembly on the project needs Newtonsoft.Json. Tried setting Specific Version=true and Copy Local=false withouth success. As React.MSBuild docs say, it is a compile time task, so I believe that the alternative is to have a copy the dependency tree in a separate folder. Do you have another solution? I moved the task from MSBuild to gulp for now (there was already a gulp step on CI).

Comment: You can try `ILMerge` the React.MSBuild dlls into a single file.

Comment: @KMoraz thanks for your suggestion. I was hoping for a solution where it would not be necessary to handle the dlls manually.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party here, but hopefully my experience will help to anyone else having the same problem.

I have recently experienced the same issue with `React.MSBuild 3.1.0.` It seems that it has hardcoded a specific version as I have updated my `Newtonsoft.Json` to the latest (10.0.3) using NuGet and set redirection correctly, but the build kept failing on the same error as you have mentioned.

What I did is simply uninstall all the React packages (MSBuild and Core) and also `Newtonsoft.Json` (using **-force** as there were other dependencies) and then let NuGet install the `React.MSBuild` again. It has installed it with all dependencies what resulted in obtaining `Newtonsoft.Json 9.0.1.`

Not sure why do they restrict `Newtonsoft.Json` library to a specific version, but it is more a question to React developers. Unless you need a latest (or other specific version of it), this should fix the problem.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but it does not resolve the issue, as I need version 10+ of Newtonsoft.Json. Best!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post...but here is my workaround:

I put `Newtonsoft.Json.dll v6.0.0.0` into `Tools` directory relative to the project directory and let msbuild copy it to `$(OutputPath)` to satisfy `TransformBabel` task condition.
My `TransformBabel.proj` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="TransformBabel">
  <!-- ReactJS.NET - Transpile JavaScript via Babel -->
  <UsingTask AssemblyFile="$(OutputPath)\React.MSBuild.dll" TaskName="TransformBabel" />
  <Target Name="TransformBabel">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Tools\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)" />
    <TransformBabel SourceDir="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

After this `TransformBabel` task is finished, then let msbuild overwrite `Newtonsoft.Json.dll v6.0.0.0` in `$(OutputPath)` with whatever `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` version my project is actually using, ex: `v8.0.3`.
So, in the main project `.csproj`, I have something like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  ...
  <Reference Include="React.MSBuild, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9aed67b161f7db78, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <HintPath>Tools\React.MSBuild.dll</HintPath>
    <Private>True</Private>
  </Reference>
  ...
</ItemGroup>
...
<ItemGroup>
  ...
  <Content Include="Tools\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" />
  <Content Include="Tools\React.MSBuild.dll" />
  ...
</ItemGroup>
...
<Target Name="TransformBabel" AfterTargets="Build">
  <Exec Command="&quot;$(msbuildtoolspath)\msbuild.exe&quot; $(ProjectDirectory)TransformBabel.proj /p:OutputPath=$(OutputPath) /nr:false" />
</Target>

<Target Name="AfterTransformBabel" AfterTargets="TransformBabel">
  <Copy SourceFiles="..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.8.0.3\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)" />
</Target>
```

Replace the path `Newtonsoft.Json.8.0.3` inside `AfterTransformBabel` task to your need.